# import a pdf presentation into libre office

Tags: libreoffice

I have a presentation in pdf and I would like to insert most of the slides into my own presentation made in odp. Is there a quicker way of doing it than slide by slide?

Comment: What is the end format you want the combined presentation of the old and new slides?